# Bootstrap-table fails with more than 1,000 rows

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-table

I have two draft pages using bootstrap-table that differ *only* in the number of rows to be shown.
more that 1,000 causes the pagination and search fields to disappear:

http://www.jeffmaynard.com/testAir/testSmall.html works fine

http://www.jeffmaynard.com/testAir/testLarge.html loses search field and pagination

The latter also produces the following warning in the console:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'columns[x].field') (2)
(anonymous function) — bootstrap-table.js:4024
each — jquery.js:381
(anonymous function) — bootstrap-table.js:4003
each — jquery.js:381
trToData — bootstrap-table.js:3995
initTable — bootstrap-table.js:4468
init — bootstrap-table.js:4310
(anonymous function) — bootstrap-table.js:7787
each — jquery.js:381
(anonymous function) — bootstrap-table.js:7762
(anonymous function) — bootstrap-table.js:7805
mightThrow — jquery.js:3762
(anonymous function) — jquery.js:3830
```

I'm sure the issue is something simple but days of trial and error (and much Googling) has not helped. Suggestions for fixing this will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `http://www.jeffmaynard.com/testAir/testLarge.html` you missed a double quote `"` in this line:

```
<tr><td class="q">CXH</td><td class="a">CYHC</td><td class="f">Vancouver Harbour Water Aerodrome (Coal Harbour Seaplane Base)</td><td class="l>Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada</td></tr>
```

you wrote `td class="l` instead of `td class="l"` so all html after that line is corrupted.

Just fix that and it will work normally.

Comment: Perfect! I spent hours looking for any such omissions (without finding it!) - wondering how you spotted it so easily?

Comment: Just export the source code into a text editor and i noticed that it was a problem in the data.